# Cant seem to work a second for loop with a pointer for an array

Tags: c++

I have a simple program that calculates for mpg using arrays and pointers
When I input miles, it works perfectly but when i input gallons I can only input until 5th. any advice?

At first when it was still a for loop it was until 3rd only but when i used try and catch it was until 5th

I tried changing ctr value after the first for loop where i inputted miles but it didnt change. I tried using do while and while loop and still

```
const int size = 10;
typedef double *pointers;
void Mperg();
void MilesPerrGallon(double *ptr1, double *ptr2);
char displayMenu(char *pt);

int main()
{
    char sagot;
    char *ptr;  
    ptr =& sagot;   
    displayMenu(ptr);
    
    switch(sagot){
        case '1':
            Mperg();
            break;
        case '2':
            cout << "toit";
            break;
        default:
            cout << sagot << " is invalid";
            break;
    }
}
void Mperg(){   
    double miles[size], gallons[size];  
    int ctr;
    pointers milPtr, galPtr;
    
    system("cls");
    cout<<"COMPUTING FOR MPG : miles per gallon...\n";
    cout<<"MILES\n";    
    galPtr = &gallons[size];
    milPtr = &miles[size];
          
    for(ctr = 0; ctr<size; ctr++){
        
        try{
            cout << "miles[" << ctr << "]: ";
            cin >> milPtr[ctr];
            
            if(milPtr[ctr] < 100 || milPtr[ctr] > 250){
                throw milPtr[ctr];      
            }
        }
        catch(double xmilPtr){
            cout << milPtr[ctr] << " is invalid!.. 100-250 only\nreenter new value\n";
            ctr--;
        }   
    }
    system("cls");
    do{ 
        for(ctr = 0; ctr<size; ctr++){      
            try{
                cout << "gallons[" << ctr << "]: ";
                cin >> galPtr[ctr];         
                if(galPtr[ctr] < 5 || galPtr[ctr] > 25){
                throw galPtr[ctr];      
                }
            }
            catch(double xgalPtr){
                cout << galPtr[ctr] << " is invalid!.. 5-25 only\nreenter new value\n";
                ctr--;
            }   
        }
   }while(ctr<size);
}
char displayMenu(char *pt)
{
    //add code here
    cout << "---------O P T I O N S---------\n";
    cout << "[1] Compute Miles Per Gallon" << endl;
    cout << "[2] Sorting of Numbers" << endl;
    cout << "[3] EXIT" << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------\n";
    cout << "Enter your choice: ";
    cin >> *pt;
         
   return *pt;
}
```

[Miles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7UFX.png)
[Gallons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DogPP.png)

Comment: Why are you not simply using `miles[i]` to access the arrays elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
galPtr = &gallons[size];
milPtr = &miles[size];
```

Since `size` is 10, this:

1. Sets `galPtr` to point to the 11th element of `gallons`.
2. Set `milPtr` to point to the 11th element of `miles`.

That's what the above code means in C++.

Of course, both arrays have only ten values, and attempting to obtain a pointer and using the pointer to modify the 11th, and subsequent, values in both arrays is undefined behavior.

You obviously meant to implement `galPtr=gallons` and `milPtr=miles`, here, although there is no real reason to use pointers this way, it doesn't accomplish anything.

Comment: nitpick: getting a pointer to the 11th element is fine, anything beyond that not

Comment: That's why the "and using the pointer to modify" is in there.